# unity передвижение объектов

Tags: unity3d

день добрый,пытаюсь передвинуть объект по x на 1 
но когда нажимаю стрелку объект  передвигается 
и возвращается на место

```
public class rotation : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 MousePos;
private float myAngle = 0f;
public float sensitivity = 1F;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    MousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Camera main = GetComponent<Camera>();
    Vector3 vector = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        float x = vector.x;
        float y = vector.y;
        float z = vector.z;

        x--;
        main.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    }
    else
    {
        main.transform.position = vector;
    }



}
// Use this for initialization
public GameObject go;
private Camera goCamera;
void Start() {
    goCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();

}
```

Comment: одна строчка if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) transform.Translate(-1, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update() //Данный метод вызывается каждый кадр
{   
Vector3 vector = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); //здесь вы объявили вектор (1,1,1)
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) //если кнопку нажали в этом кадре выполняется то, что указано ниже.
{
    float x = vector.x;
    float y = vector.y;
    float z = vector.z;

    x--;
    main.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);

}
else //если кнопка не была нажата в этом кадре, то позиция объекта устанавливается в точку (1,1,1), т.к. это значение переменной vector
{
    main.transform.position = vector;
}
```

В итоге каждый кадр у вас происходит проверка была ли нажата в этом кадре кнопка. Если нажата позиция устанавливается согласно вашим преобразованиям, если не была нажата, то в точку *vector*, которую вы ранее объявили, как *new Vector3(1, 1, 1);*